# PHPmyADMIN Errors after upgrade of MySQL

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

All,

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 LTS and had a client needing MySQL 7.0+, so upgraded, but now can not login either via PHPmyAdmin or MySQL Workbench.  Kubuntu/Ubuntu 14.04 typically runs on either MySQL 5 or 6.

I know there were changes to the login and wonder if there is a version of PHPmyAdmin, that I can load to correct this.  If I try the typical install methods for 14.04, it always gives me the old 5/6 version of PHPmyADMIN & MySQL Workbench, so need to know how to upgrade.

No not upgrading to 16.04 LTS, because have tried that on 3 machines already and every single one crashed, because of a bug in the upgrade, so not doing that as backup and recovery way to time consuming.  Especially since though I have well over 1,000 hours in attempting to install CloneZilla, it has never ever successfully installed on any of the 20 machines I run.

Cheers!

Comment: Oh, ideally I need to be running both MySQL 6 & 7 as I now have clients using both.  I could seperate these onto seperate machines, but would rather have them both on each machine.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? It sounds like you're using the older version provided by your distribution package manager, but you can always download your own recent version from phpmyadmin.net and follow the guide at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html.

Comment: Yes Isaac, that is the problem.  14.04 running through either "Software Center" or Synaptic, only allows the version for 14.04, which is a MySQL 5/6 version.  Needing the later version, but when I download installation is a challenge as there is no HOWTO for MySQL 7 or phpMyAdmin 4.7.6 for my OS as the official word from Ubuntu is "not supported"

Comment: MySQL 7+ & phpMyAdmin 4.7+ is officially supported for Kubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but since the installer for the upgrade has bugs, and kills every single machine where you attemp an upgrade, I'm not willing to take 3 days or more of down time to bang through the backup and upgrade.

Comment: The simplest way I've found to upgrade, is:
  1.) Burn 16.04 LTS to Live DVD, 
  2.) Format a section of the existing HD,
  3.) Move all needed files, including configs to the new section,
  4.) Boot the Live DVD and select install,
  5.) At formatting use all space except the new HD section,
  6.) Finish a clean install,
  7.) Move the needed files back,
  8.) Slug through 3 months of reinstalling apps and configs needed for 100% restoration.
Not a good solution by any means. Have tried but still find no way to actually upgrade
without all this extra work, so just don't upgrade!

Comment: PS:
As heavy developer running 2TB HD and have well over 10M files, over 1,000 apps, so this is 
a huge undertaking.  You see why this does not excite me at all.